# Get URL of parent page from a sub page

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript code below to put my menu item to class active when I'm on the page for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ it works. But I also wanna put the menu item to class active when I'm at the subpages like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/, may I know how to do that?

```
    <script>
      var url = window.parent.location.href;
      $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

      $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use `String.prototype.match`

```
<script>
  var url = window.parent.location.href;
  $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

  $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return (url.match(this.href) !== null);
  }).parent().addClass('active');
</script>
```